# CSS doesn't apply to an included PHP file

Tags: php, html, css, include

I want to separate my code to make it clearer. To do so, instead of having one big php file I spare them and keep one "main" file where I include the others when I need. The problem is that CSS only apply to the "main" file, but not to included files.

I'm pretty sure this is not a path issue, for I'm working with every files in the same folder (I know it's not the best way to work, but so far I only have few files so it's not a big deal). I have double checked eventual writing mistakes.

Here is my "main" php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A very nice title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="style1.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head> 

<body>
    <?php include("file2.php"); ?>
</body>
```

and here is my "file2.php" file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="style1.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head> 

<div class="beer">
    <img src="simple_beer.png" alt="beer picture"/>
    <div class="description>
        <p> a simple text </p>
        <form id="add" action="[nothing interesting]">
            <input type="number>
            <input type="submit" value="add to card">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i'm using the same CSS files for both php files. But it's not working on the file2.php when I have a look at it (I'm working on a local host). I've tried to delete cache from my browser (firefox). If you're wondering why I'm working on php files instead of HTML, it's simply because I intend to add php code later.

I have been looking for a solution for almost two hours, nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can't repeat `DOCTYPE `, `html`, `head` etc.  That's not valid.

Comment: Your include should only be the bits of html you need to include - not the whole document

Comment: Your html markup is invalid... file2.php should start on `<div class="beer">` not html,head

Comment: Now file2.php starts right at the <div class="beer"> and ends with </div> and I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you browsing directly to file2.php? if so then it won't be styled - the nature of includes is that you include it in a file that has all the header and body, etc which includes the style sheets.  If you are wanting file2.php to be browsable, then your file 2 needs to be like main and then make a third include file that you include in both

Comment: Can you include your css file also

Answer (score 1):

Include everything header-related inside main.php file, remove head section from file2.php and then include file2.php in the body section of main.php. When you include that file, it will get everything that is above. That means whatever you have in main.php before include() function, will be accessible in called file (thanks to that you can link everything once and have it available in all called files).

Include() brings full code structure from the called file which you do not need (talking about head tag) if main file will hold everything that you need inside  tag.

Comment: Even after removing header from file2.php and including it into the body of my main it doesn't work. I don't understand. At this points my file2.php contains only HTML instructions.